# Laravel / MVC: where to return partial response data

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

Edit: This question is more about how to create a contract within a function. How do I create methods that do simple things and have requirements between objects? Do I:

1) Add checks and exceptions in the start() method to create the contract and put the pausing loop in a different call? (Downside here is a minor repeat call to the data source.)

2) Add an event listener for whenever a timer is started to create the contract? (I'm not sure I can return data the way I would like with this method. I'm also not sure I can guarantee that the event will complete successfully before I start the new timer. May not matter that much in this case.)

3) Just return the ids from the start function and process them. (The function will be doing too much, but at least it will work properly with less overhead.)

========================================================================

I have this code in my model. This is a timer application and this code gets hit when starting a timer. Basically, any running timers should get paused and somehow the view needs to understand that it should refresh those timers.

```
public function start($input = array())
{
    if($timers = TimeLog::where('status','running')->get()){
        foreach($timers as $timer){
            /** @var $timer TimeLog **/
            $timer->pause();
        }
    }
    $this->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $this->addDetails($input);
    $this->restarted_at = date('Y-n-d H:i:s'); //TODO timezones
    $this->status = 'running';
    $this->save();
}
```

I'm uncomfortable returning a list of paused timers from this function. Just doesn't seem to make sense.

I thought about moving the foreach to my controller, but this is really business logic and I wanted to make sure no running timers exist when I start a timer.

I could make another method in this class, which would solve the return issue, but then how do I guarantee that each start call will check for running timers?

Comment: you could add a method to your model, `getPausedTimers` that returns an array of paused timers or maybe just the IDs of the paused timers if your setup is like that...I don't really understand what this program does though. As far as I can tell this whole thing would be better off as javascript

Comment: State is preserved in the DB. I see you're suggesting option 3 above, but that means either decoupling a process that I want coupled (for better or worse) or keeping it coupled but then returning unrelated values from an object method.

Comment: Hmm. I think Laravel really should implement an actual business layer

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a good fit for using the repository pattern as described [here](http://culttt.com/2013/07/08/creating-flexible-controllers-in-laravel-4-using-repositories/).

I recently had to solve a similar problem since I am just getting started with Laravel and I was putting all my business logic in either `Model` or `Controller` classes. I had business logic that didn't seem to make sense for either of those, and after some research I found `Repositories`.

I would try something like this:

```
class EloquentTimerRepository implements TimerRepository
{
    /**
    * Part of your TimerRepository interface
    */
    public function startTimersForCurrentUser($inputs)
    {
        $this->pauseRunningTimers();
        $newTimer = $this->createNewTimer($inputs);
        $newTimer->start();
    }

    private function createNewTimer($inputs)
    {
        $timer = new Timer;
        $timer->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $timer->addDetails($input);
        $timer->save();

        return $timer;
    }

    private function getRunningTimers()
    {
        return TimeLog::where('status','running');
    }

    private function pauseRunningTimers()
    {
        if($this->getRunningTimers()){
            foreach($timers as $timer){
                /** @var $timer TimeLog **/
                $timer->pause();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then:

```
class Timer extends Model
{       
    public function start()
    {
        $this->restarted_at = date('Y-n-d H:i:s'); //TODO timezones
        $this->status = 'running';
        $this->save();
    }
}
```

As for updating the view, you're going to have to either do a page reload or if you are using ajax, make a subsequent call to pull the latest timers and reset the page elements based on that data. There are probably ways to implement push (from the server) but I'm not familiar with those techniques yet.

Comment: I separated the save() calls in the `createNewTimer()` and `start()`, but you could revert back to using one by moving to a function that does both the **create timer** and **start timer** actions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My question is more: If I want to get paused timers as part of my response, where should I get this paused timer list? I don't want to make a separate request (although with zeromq I could add a listener and that might solve this entirely).